# Code value is supposed to change every time so the same seat does not display but it doesn’t

Tags: c++, return-value

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  airline ticket
//
//  Created by has on 5/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 has. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
```

this part is the function
the function does not keep its value or return 1 atlest

```
int place(int plane[],int count){
    int seat = 0;
    seat = count+1;
    plane[count]=1;
    return seat;
}
```

this is where it begins 
this is sopposed to keep the value of the previous seat sold as 1 and give the next seats number

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int count; int plane[20]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, seat;
    for (count=0; count < 20; count++)
    {
        if(plane[count] == 0)
        {
            place(&plane[count], count);
            cout<< " this is your seat number for the flight "<< seat<<endl;

            return 0;
        }
        if(plane[19]!=0)
        {
            cout<< " the first calss seats are all booked, we may have secondary class avabile would like to try"<<endl;
        }

    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `count` is a local variable in your function `place` and so it will not update your *other* variable `count`.

Comment: @user3600306 try looking up [variable scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) and [pass by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

Comment: You can write `int plane[20] = { };` - any omitted initializers are treated as if `0` was given for them

Comment: i have a new question related to this... could you guys please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the return value. Change:

```
place(&plane[count], count);
```

to

```
seat = place(&plane[count], count);
```

Some compilers would give a warning that you use `seat` uninitialized, on the line after that... if your compiler did not warn you, then try turning up its warning level.